# MediaPlayer not playing after reopening the app

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-lifecycle, onresume, onpause

When i add mediaplayer.start in onResume i was expecting to start the audio when i reopen the the app but it dindt start it

```
public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
int length = 0;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.andhadhun);
        mediaPlayer.start();
}
 @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        length = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(MediaPlayer::start);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, It pauses the `MediaPlayer` in `onStop` and resume in `onResume`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok try this code

```
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.test);
        mediaPlayer.start();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if(mediaPlayer!=null)
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(mediaPlayer!=null) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not working , so i tried to put in try catch but still giving error , Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:1327)
        at com.example.philosophicalquotes.HomeActivity.onResume(HomeActivity.java:451)

Comment: I have changed code, you can use length to seek to position then start too

Comment: sorry but it is not working not playing audio when i reopen app

Comment: i just ran the code and it is working for me, do 1 thing try creating a demo Activity and only use the code i gave u and try it out

Comment: Are you getting any other errors??

Comment: no im not getting any error